# Программа перестает отправлять команды "умной" лампочке спустя определенное кол-во срабатываний

Tags: c#, winforms, сокет

Пишу программу на winforms для управления умной лампочкой. Язык C#. Все по мануалу от разработчиков yeelight(XiaoMi). Программа отправляет приветственное сообщение по UDP на мультикаст адресс, получает ответ от лампочки, парсит его, после чего устанавливает TCP соединение. Тут у меня все отлично. Но вот что не так. Пока что программа позволяет пользователю делать "вкл/выкл" на "Enter" и регулировать "яркость" при помощи "PgUp/PgDn". Проблема в том, что лампочка, судя по всему, перестает реагировать спустя какое-то кол-во нажатий, хоть в форме, хоть на клавиатуре. Дело или в форме, или в отправке данных. Мне кажется, что что-то где-то забивается, т. к. время роли не играет, я засекал. Хотя теперь я выяснил, что спустя какое-то время(10-15 сек.) все продолжает работать. Но такое поведение программы все равно не нормально.

Сначала вариант с сетевым потоком:

Это свойства MiBulb:

```
private TcpClient TcpClient;
private NetworkStream Stream;
```

Сразу в конструкторе XiaoMi-лампочки эти свойства инициализируются:

```
    public MiBulb()
    {
        string DeviceAnswer = ExploreDevice(); //это UDP запрос-ответ
        ParseProps(DeviceAnswer); //Тут понятно

        TcpClient = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        if(!TcpClient.Connected)//Не помню зачем, но вроде не мешает
        {
            TcpClient.Connect(TcpEndpoint);
        }

        Stream = TcpClient.GetStream();
    }
```

А эти методы лампочки привязаны к кнопкам формы и на горячие клавиши, тут лампочке передаются команды в Json формате. Если их часто "тыкать" лампочка перестает реагировать:

```
    public void PowerToggle()
    {
        string commandJson = "{\"id\":" + DeviceProperties.GetID() + ",\"method\":\"toggle\",\"params\":[]}\r\n";
        byte[] command = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(commandJson);
        Stream.Write(command, 0, command.Length);
        DeviceProperties.Power = !(DeviceProperties.Power);
    }

    public void IncreaseBrigtness()
    {
        if (DeviceProperties.Brightness < 100)
        {
            string commandJson = "{\"id\":" + DeviceProperties.GetID() +
                                ",\"method\":\"set_bright\",\"params\":[" +
                                (DeviceProperties.Brightness + 10) +
                                ", \"smooth\", 0]}\r\n";
            byte[] command = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(commandJson);

            Stream.Write(command, 0, command.Length);
            DeviceProperties.Brightness += 10;
        }
    }

    public void DecreaseBrigtness()
    {
        if (DeviceProperties.Brightness > 0)
        {
            string commandJson = "{\"id\":" + DeviceProperties.GetID() + 
                                ",\"method\":\"set_bright\",\"params\":[" + 
                                (DeviceProperties.Brightness - 10) + 
                                ", \"smooth\", 0]}\r\n";
            byte[] command = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(commandJson);

            Stream.Write(command, 0, command.Length);
            DeviceProperties.Brightness -= 10;
        }
    }
```

А вот так привязаны эти методы к кнопкам:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private MiBulb Bulb = null;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Bulb = new MiBulb();

        KeyPreview = true;
        KeyDown += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.PageDown) BrightnessDOWNButton_Click(BrightnessDOWNButton, null);
            if (e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.PageUp) BrightnessUPButton_Click(BrightnessUPButton, null);
        };
    }
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void PowerToggleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bulb.PowerToggle();
    }

    private void BrightnessUPButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bulb.IncreaseBrigtness();
    }

    private void BrightnessDOWNButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bulb.DecreaseBrigtness();
    }

    private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.Down)
        {
            BrightnessDOWNButton.PerformClick();
        }
        if (e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.Up)
        {
            BrightnessUPButton.PerformClick();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверяйте делается ли хандлу сокета или другого обьекта Close. В HttpWebRequest  - если не делать Close - он потом не работает. Скорее всего незакрытые хандлы накапливаются и после определенного числа - сокеты перестают работать. Проверьте закрываются ли ваши TcpClient

Comment: также я бы проверял состояние подключения, когда всё перестает работать. Возможно он просто сбрасывается или надо пошаманить с keep alive параметрами

Comment: @nick_n_a Так я же один раз создаю TcpClient в конструкторе, и в деструкторе его закрываю. Или его нужно каждый раз создавать, коннектить и закрывать при каждой операции?

Comment: @nick_n_a Как выяснилось через время лампочка продолжает реагировать, я теперь вообще не знаю что это. Она то ли в защиту уходит при множественных запросах.. Я то хотел в перспективе сделать что-то вроде Ambient Light.. Понятно что через UDP, теперь фиг знает, может ли она так вообще. Но в объекте Stream я откопал какие-то неопознанные исключения по поводу Length и Position. Если копнуть еще глубже, то типа stream не поддреживает seek операции. Проблема это или норма не знаю.

Comment: У вас пакеты одинаковой длинны? Попробуйте установить в SendBufferSize  вашу длинну пакета, или более маленькое число там 16 или 32.  Возможно кеш мешает. С TcpClient не работал, работал с сокетами, там нужно было к-во посланых байт контролировать.

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо вам за ответы. Насчет размера буфера я понял. По поводу лампочки, я выяснил, что я тормоз. Проблема не в коде. Еще раз прочитал внимательно мануал. Там большими красными буквами:"For each connection, there is a command message quota, 
that is 60 commands per minute". Это решается включением режима "music", там уже лампочка выступает в качестве клиента и ограничения снимаются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вобщем я нашел ответ на свой вопрос в инструкции к лампочке. Когда она выступает в качестве сервера, она поддерживает не более 144-х запросов в минуту для 4-х клиентов, и не более 60 запросов в мин. для одного. Решается включением в ней режима "music", который поддерживает иммитацию светомузыки(или чего угодно). В этом случае лампочка выступает в роли клиента, а ПК становится сервером. В таком варианте ограничений нет.